# IIS 404 detailed error visible. Server files directory is exposed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, iis-7, custom-errors

I have an Angular application hosted on IIS. In my application there is a custom 404 error page for incorrect urls. However, whenever a js file is requested from the url https://mywebsite.com/assets/js/Mordernizer.min.js (with .js extension), it displays IIS detailed error page, exposing physical directory of the application. When the URL is https://mywebsite.com/assets/js/Mordernizer.min (without .js extension), the custom error page works as expected.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the https://mywebsite.com/assets/js/Mordernizer.min.js file exist?  Does your Web.config file have any rewrite rules?  I've seen something similar when you have a rewrite rule that rewrites to an incorrect location.

Comment: "However, whenever a js file is requested from the url https://mywebsite.com/assets/js/Mordernizer.min.js (with .js extension), it displays IIS detailed error page, exposing physical directory of the application" is incorrect. You saw that detailed error page, because you were using `http://localhost:4200` to access IIS on the same machine. IIS won't show the detailed error page if you access from outside that machine. Read more about `DetailedLocalOnly` in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/

Comment: @LexLi Yes i have set up Single page application (Angular) inside my .Net Core startup file. Is that the reason my - errorMode = "Custom"  won't work? Also the 404 Error Page (screenshot above) that i got is configured in Angular routing. I guess my web.config settings never worked. What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved! I just had to set httpErrors configuration in web.config file at Angular level (dist folder). All this time I was modifying the Asp.net Core application web.config file. Silly mistake, anyway thanks!